# Android: correct usage of PrepareAsync() in media player activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) tutorial, but the usage of prepareAsync is not clear and my code does not output any audio. I'm using prepareAsync() because my mp3 is online and I don't want to lock the activity during media player preparing. Could you explain basic usage of prepareAsync?

```
package com.example.simplemediaplayer.app;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MediaPlayerActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "tag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);

        String url = "http://www.brothershouse.narod.ru/music/pepe_link_-_guitar_vibe_113_club_mix.mp3"; // your URL here
        MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "mp3 not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.media_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution is to call the setOnPreparedListener of myMediaPlayer object and wait until prepareAsync() method has finished.

```
package com.example.simplemediaplayer.app;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MediaPlayerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "tag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);

        String url = "http://www.brothershouse.narod.ru/music/pepe_link_-_guitar_vibe_113_club_mix.mp3"; // your URL here
        MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "mp3 not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //mp3 will be started after completion of preparing...
        myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                player.start();
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.media_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a MainActivity with multiple buttons (each button plays different mp3s from raw folder thorough a MediaPlayerAsynch class that I want to create.) I want to send some parameters from MainActivity to this MediaPlayerAsynch class to play mp3s. This MediaPlayerAsynch class will handle mp3 playback requests from MainActivity asynchronously. And if I request another song before the current playback is not finished, it will stop the playback and start the new song. This is what I use now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730394/one-public-media-player-class-to-be-used-across-all-activities

Comment: Can you please guide me or show me a little demo. Because the code I use works but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` method is used to prepare the `MediaPlayer` instance for playback asynchronously. This method is typically used when playing both local and remote media sources.

When playing a local media source, you can use the `mediaPlayer.prepare()` method, which prepares the **MediaPlayer** instance for playback synchronously. However, when playing a remote media source, such as a media file from a server, it's recommended to use the `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` method to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Using `prepareAsync()` allows the MediaPlayer to prepare the media source in a background thread, without blocking the UI thread. This is important because preparing a remote media source may take some time, and blocking the UI thread can cause the app to become unresponsive and result in a poor user experience.

***In short, you can use `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` method for both local and remote media sources, but it is particularly useful when playing remote media sources to avoid blocking the UI thread.***