# Android MediaPlayer play MP3 from service

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am brand new (47 minutes) into Android development and have a problem that I have is likely to be a simple one.

Anyway, here it is.

I would like to use a web service which, given a url, spits back an Mp3 (browser instantly starts downloading it).

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)  getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);

String url = "http://www.gimme-an-mp3.com/xyz";

try {
    player.setDataSource(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
player.prepareAsync();
player.start();
```

For some reason, the media player does not play my Mp3 file. Why? Do I have to first download it and then pass it to the media player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call player.start() only after player has been prepared. 
before that, the player is still preparing.

```
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { 
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

more details can be found here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

and here [Android: correct usage of PrepareAsync() in media player activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309857/android-correct-usage-of-prepareasync-in-media-player-activity)