# MediaPlayer.Prepare() has been thrown when I try to next track

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

If I replace a "prepare()" method into a "prepareasync()" that's fine but Media will not play.

If I use a "prepare()"then I got error's has been thrown .
Please help me

```C#
 OnCreate(....)

//Media
player = new MediaPlayer ();
player.Stop ();
```

```C#
public void StartMedia(string url_string)
{
Load_Data ();
seekBar.Max = player.Duration;

player.Stop ();
player.Reset ();
player.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
player.SetDataSource(url_string);
player.Prepare();
player.Start ();
imgPlayorPause.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_pause_black_36dp);
//UpdatedTimerTask ();
UpdateProcessBar ();
}
```

```C#
public void NextTracks(int positon)
{
if (Isrepeat == false) {
if (positon >= mListData.Count ()) {
mPosition = 1;
} else {
mPosition++;

    }
} else {
    mPosition = positon;
}

StartMedia(mListData [mPosition].stream_url + "?client_id=" + clienId);
}
```

I have tried some ways but that is not success.
[image]

Comment: Your mean public override void StartMedia(string url_string)

Comment: I don't understand you meaning

Comment: So are you using local or remote (web) media? If so use prepareAsync(); it will work, but you have to override the Callback associated with it once its prepared.

Comment: remote media. source from https://.......

Comment: Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23310885/4252352 - use prepareAsync();

Comment: setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() doesn't support on xamarin android

Comment: Document: public void setOnPreparedListener (MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player.Prepared+= (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
            player.Start();
        };
```

This is fine and solve this problem.