# One public media player class to be used across all activities

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Updated.

After the recommendations, I decided to run media player in a new thread. Because I need Media Player only when activities are on the screen. Here is the new code:

First, my public SingleMP (Media Player) class used in multiple classes:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;

public class SingleMP implements Runnable
{
    public static MediaPlayer mp;
    private static Context context;
    private static Uri uri;

    public SingleMP(Context context, Uri uri){
    this.context= context;
    this.uri= uri;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    // Called in OnDestroy of used class.
    public static void mpstop()
    {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And an example of using it in another Java class:

```
public class MainMenu
{
    private Uri uri;
    private Runnable MPthread;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        RadioButton rbtnA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rbtnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Assign a sound from raw folder.
                uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/nice");
                MPthread = new SingleMP(MainMenu.this, uri));
                new Thread(MPthread).start();               
                }
             }
        });

        RadioButton rbtnB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rbtnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Assign a sound from raw folder.
                uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/morning");
                MPthread = new SingleMP(MainMenu.this, uri));
                new Thread(MPthread).start();
                }
             }
         });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

    if(MPthread!=null) {
        SingleMP.mpstop();
    }

    }
}
```

What do you think? It seems that my UI works a little bit smoother.

Answer (score 3):

Your media player instance is going to live on the main thread, which is the UI thread. This is not recommended.

I would probably create a service that would create a new thread holding the media player. Each of your activities could then bind to the service to control the media player.

See section [Extending the service class](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

You can also look at [the media player sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer).

Comment: I moved Media Player to a thread. But I'm not sure if I'm calling it properly from the other classes..

Comment: What do you mean? I think, I moved it to a new thread.  @VyshnavRamesh

Comment: After my researches I saw that you need a service when you want to do things even when your app is not working. I do not need that. So I just moved it to a new thread as I need media player only when app is running. But I'm not so sure I'm doing threading right. @VyshnavRamesh