# freeze android app when playing music of server

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an online music player and my problem is when user press on play button
my app freeze for 1 or 2 second(network speed).
I play music of a link of my server and put it in Voice variable and play stream that.
whats the problem of my code?
Thanks.

My code:

```
detail_voice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(detail_date, " " + "دارم میگیرررررررررمش :| :)))", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

        snackbar.show();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(Voice);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            detail_voice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            detail_voice_stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

detail_voice_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        detail_voice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        detail_voice_stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        detail_voice_stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did my answer fully answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is not extensive, but my guess is your problem might indeed have to do with loading your data over the network. Usually when loading data over a network, you'll want to do that *asynchronously* to avoid the program needlessly waiting for the data, and freeze during that time.

The MediaPlayer class has a *prepareAsync()* method which will do this for you. But, you cannot put the *start()* method below that anymore as it is now asynchronous. Try **replacing** this code:

```
mp.setDataSource(Voice);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

With this:

```
mp.setDataSource(Voice);
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }
});
mp.prepareAsync();
```

If that code solves the problem, your connection was indeed the problem. You should **not** however use the *setOnPreparedListener()* method every time you click. I'd suggest moving it outside the *onClickListener()* method so it is only executed once.

[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309857/android-correct-usage-of-prepareasync-in-media-player-activity) has a good implementation too. It might be worth a read as well.